# how to show .kml file on MapBox

Tags: android, mapbox, kml

I want to show .kml file data on MapBox, this .kml file has the origin and destination information and I want to draw a path from origin to destination.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would advice you to convert the kml file to a geojson file. Afterwards you can use a GeoJSONSource and a LineLayer to show your path.

Comment: how to convert ?
Can you please suggest me the best way to do it.

Comment: something as https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/kml-to-geojson would work

Comment: @Tobrun Thanks for that.
Another thing I want to know is that, is it really possible to show kml file on MapBox?

Comment: this isn't a supported feature atm though we are working on the concept of a custom source which would make it easy to plug something in as a KmlSource.

Comment: @Tobrun thanks you for update.
Please suggest me some library so that I can convert .kml file to geoJson programatically.

Comment: I'm not aware of any java libs atm, here is a js equivalent that could be ported easily to java https://github.com/mapbox/togeojson

Comment: Feature request to port this to java in https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/issues/564